# Найти все .py файлы в папке и изменить их код

Tags: python, cmd

Скачал с GitHub репозиторий для работы с языком (лингвистика), но к сожалению он написан на python 2, а у меня python 3 компилятор. Я знаю, что есть встроенная библиотека 2to3, которая меняет исходный код файла с python 2 на python 3 этой командой

```
C:\myDir>2to3 -w -n myFile.py
```

Файлов очень много, по этому мне хотелось бы узнать, возможно ли найти все файлы с расширением .py в этой папке или во всех дочерних и применить к ним эту команду

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример из доки:

> To translate an entire project from one directory tree to another use:

```
$ 2to3 --output-dir=python3-version/mycode -W -n python2-version/mycode
```